# Empty lines next to a wrapfigure

Tags: graphics

My problem is that I want LaTeX to insert empty lines next to an image until it ends. (Sorry for the terrible wording, I am no native speaker and don't know how to express it...)

Here is how it currently looks:
[image]

And this is how I'd like it to look (Taken from Word):
[image]

Is there any way to accomplish what is shown in the second picture dynamically?

Here is a MWS of my code, although it doesn't do much:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example}
\end{wrapfigure} 
This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose. 
\\
This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This 
should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should 
be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. 

\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could try to put the text in a `parbox` with a width of `\textwidth`- width of the figure. Then measure the height of this box and insert `\vspace` (height of the image - height of `\parbox`), if the height of the image is greater than that of the text.

Comment: never use `\\ ` like this! `purpose. 
\\
This`

Comment: note if you use `example-image` rather than `example` in test files then they work as posted (`example-image` is in the distributions for such test uses)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\clearwrapfig{%
\ifnum\c@WF@wrappedlines>\@ne\mbox{}\par\expandafter\clearwrapfig\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example-image}
\end{wrapfigure} 
This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose. 

\clearwrapfig

This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This 
should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should 
be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. 


\end{document}
```

Comment: This works exactly as intended and is kept very neat!

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to get this right -- I hope it is not too similar to the other answers… :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\usepackage{mwe}    % Provides example images

\newlength{\wrapfheight}    % Height of the image
\newlength{\wraptheight}    % Height of the text beside the image
\newlength{\wraptwidth}        % Width of the text
\newlength{\wrapstrut}        % Amount of space to be inserted below the text

\newsavebox{\wrapf}            % Holds the image
\newsavebox{\wrapt}            % Holds the text

% Wrapper for combining image and one paragraph of text
% #1: image width    #2: image file     #3 text paragraph
\newcommand{\wraptextfigure}[3]{%
    \savebox{\wrapf}{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}%
    \setlength{\wrapfheight}{\totalheightof{\usebox{\wrapf}}}%

    \setlength{\wraptwidth}{\textwidth - #1 -\columnsep}%
    \savebox{\wrapt}{\parbox[t]{\wraptwidth}{#3}}%
    \setlength{\wraptheight}{\totalheightof{\usebox{\wrapt}}}%

    \noindent%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{#1}%
            \vspace*{-\intextsep}\usebox{\wrapf}%
        \end{wrapfigure}%
        #3%
     % If the image is higher than the text insert rule …
        \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\wraptheight < \wrapfheight}}{%
            \setlength{\wrapstrut}{\wrapfheight - \wraptheight + \intextsep}%
            \rule[-\wrapstrut]{0pt}{\wrapstrut}}%
    % Otherwise add just some vertical space
            {\vspace{1ex}}%
    \end{minipage}%
}



\begin{document}

\noindent\hrulefill\\

\wraptextfigure{5.5cm}{example-image-a}{This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose.}

This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine.

\wraptextfigure{10cm}{example-image-a}{This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose.}

This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine.

\end{document}
```

Comment: note that you don't need the mwe package to access the example images, even though they are distributed with that package,

Comment: it looks really good, but MikTex can't get the xifthen package for some reason

Answer (score 1):

I'd propose not to use warpfig for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{6.6cm}
This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose. 
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[h]{5.5cm}
\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{example}
\end{minipage}\\
This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This 
should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should 
be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can play with the alignments of the minipages in order to get your desired output. (Need to run now.)

Comment: I am afraid that should the text be longer than the picture, it will not automatically take the space back. Any ideas how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is some modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newlength{\myfill}
\newlength{\myrfill}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newsavebox{\mytbox}
\newsavebox{\myvbox}
\def\myfillcreate{\pgfmathsetmacro\numlines{int(((\lengthtoadd-\lengthtoremove)/(\baselineskip))+2)}\ifnum\numlines>0 \foreach\line in{1,...,\numlines}{\\}\fi}%
\newcommand\includewrapedgraphics[2][]{\savebox\mybox{\vbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}\setlength{\myfill}{\dimexpr\the\dp\mybox+\the\ht\mybox}\xdef\lengthtoadd{\the\myfill}}%
\def\getmytext#1{\savebox\mytbox{\hbox{#1}}%
\savebox\myvbox{\vbox{#1}}%
\setlength{\myrfill}{\dimexpr\ht\myvbox+\dp\myvbox}%
\ifdim\lengthtoadd>\myrfill%
\xdef\lengthtoremove{\the\myrfill}%
\else%
\xdef\lengthtoremove{0pt}%
\fi%
}%

%#1={first wrapfigure argument (r,l etc)}
%#2={second wrapfigure argument (width)}
%#3={first (optional) includegraphics argument (width, keepaspectratio etc)}
%#4={image name of includegraphics}
%#5={the rest of the text}
\newcommand\mywrapedfigure[5]{%
\includewrapedgraphics[#3]{#4}%
\begin{wrapfigure}{#1}{#2}%
\getmytext{#5}%
\usebox{\mybox}%
\end{wrapfigure}#5%
\myfillcreate
}

\begin{document}

%#1={first wrapfigure argument (r,l etc)}
%#2={second wrapfigure argument (width)}
%#3={first (optional) includegraphics argument (width, keepaspectratio etc)}
%#4={image name of includegraphics}
%#5={the rest of the text}
\mywrapedfigure{tr}{5.5cm}{width=5.5cm}{example-image-a}{% 
This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose.}

This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This 
should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should 
be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine.

\mywrapedfigure{r}{5.5cm}{width=5.5cm}{example-image-a}{% 
This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose.This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose.}


This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This 
should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should 
be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine.


\mywrapedfigure{r}{5.5cm}{width=5.5cm}{example-image-a}{% 
This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose.This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning}

This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This 
should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should 
be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine.



\mywrapedfigure{r}{5.5cm}{width=5.5cm}{example-image-a}{% 
This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose.This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no }

This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This 
should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should 
be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine.


\mywrapedfigure{r}{5.5cm}{width=5.5cm}{example-image-a}{% 
This is an example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an 
example text with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text 
with no particular meaning or purpose. This is an example text with no 
particular meaning or purpose. }

This should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This 
should be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine. This should 
be below the imagine. This should be below the imagine.


\end{document}
```

Usage is explained two times in the example (one on preamble, one on definition)...

Output:

[image]