# Should I keep trying to write a portfolio in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

I'm applying to an art school with a process portfolio (picture oriented thesis)

As already asked [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70906/how-to-put-pictures-on-the-right-and-left-side-of-text-in-org-mode-for-latex-exp/70914#70914) I need to create sections with an intro picture and explain the artistic process with 30-50 words paragraphs alongside many pictures I've taken. Instead on the content, I've spent the last days with floating & layout issues as e.g.

- List of figures intermixed with pictures
- Invisible `label` fragments in the exported latex distorting the picture & accompanying text alignment
- Pictures being at the page bottom instead their appropriate section

Before trying another hacky attempt to get a picture and some text positioned as per [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70906/how-to-put-pictures-on-the-right-and-left-side-of-text-in-org-mode-for-latex-exp/70914#70914) I'd like to know if I'm missing a blogpost/workflow/approach or just accept the obvious:

**Ditch org-mode and use InDesign like every other visual arts student**

Note: I've been repeatedly told to ask org related latex questions here instead on emacs sx.

Edit: I've pasted the [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70906/how-to-put-pictures-on-the-right-and-left-side-of-text-in-org-mode-for-latex-exp/70914#70914) below:

---

I'm stuck on a trial and error loop testing the [latex export settings](https://orgmode.org/manual/Images-in-LaTeX-export.html) to no avail.

What I want:

```
+---------+
|         |
| Pic     |
|         |
+----+----+---+
|Pic |Txt     |
|    |        |
+----+--------+
|Txt |Pic     |
|    |        |
+----+--------+
```

What I have (pdf screenshot):
[image: pdf screenshot]

```
#+options: toc:nil
* Foo
#+NAME: fig:top
#+CAPTION: Section intro
[[./kitten.jpg]]
Text below ref:fig:top

#+NAME: fig:left
#+CAPTION: left figure
#+ATTR_LATEX: :float wrap :width 0.38\textwidth :placement {l}{0.4\textwidth}
[[./kitten.jpg]]

I must be on the same line as figure ref:fig:left

#+NAME: fig:right
#+CAPTION: right figure
#+ATTR_LATEX: :float wrap :width 0.38\textwidth :placement {r}{0.4\textwidth}
[[./kitten.jpg]]

I must be on the same line as figure ref:fig:right
```

The kitten source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cute_grey_kitten.jpg

Comment: Are your only options org-mode and InDesign?

Comment: it seems to be an org mode question (so off topic) rather than a latex one. Obviously if you need to closely control the latex it is easier to write the latex directly rather than rely on whatever latex org mode generates. Your comments about picture positioning are hard to understand if you show no code. LateX includes pictures with `\includegraphics` and positions them with the same code that it positions a letter such as `X` they appear exactly where you place them, unless you specify that they may be moved.

Comment: What is org mode?

Comment: @PeterWilson https://orgmode.org/

Comment: don't expect people here to have org mode, use `example-image` test image (as we have that) and show the generated latex. We can debug that for you, how to get org mode to generate correct latex for you is off topic here. (Or as I said earlier you could consider simply writing the latex directly, which is what most people here would do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

org mode setup is off topic here, but getting the ouput that you sketch with LaTeX seems fairly standard:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig,capt-of,parskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{abc}
\end{center}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{abc qqq}
\end{wrapfigure}
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 


\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{.3\textwidth}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\captionof{figure}{xyz qqq}
\end{wrapfigure}
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 
Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. Some text here. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've replaced "Some text.." with `\lipsum[1][1]` and my problem is back. What solution works with *any text amount*? Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/czw0ZR1.png

Comment: @jjk presumably wrapfig gave a warning about that, so you can add extra blank lines to hold the image (I think I have an aswer on this site somewhere that does that automatically) if yor images are the same size so you need a minimum of (say) 5 lines per paragraph it is fairly easy to automaically pad any short paragraphs,

Comment: Yes indeed,  and @jjk [found it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/418940/empty-lines-next-to-a-wrapfigure/418986#418986) and posted it  as a comment on his [original question on Emacs SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70906/how-to-put-pictures-on-the-right-and-left-side-of-text-in-org-mode-for-latex-exp/70946#70946) which completes the circle :-)