# What is causing the vertical distance between a float picture and the text alongside

Tags: wrapfigure

I want the picture and the text vertically aligned
[image: screenshot]

```latex
% Created 2022-03-14 Mon 19:25
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter\def\clearwrapfig{\ifnum\c@WF@wrappedlines>\@ne\mbox{}\par\expandafter\clearwrapfig\fi}\makeatother
\date{\today}
\title{}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={},
 pdftitle={},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 27.2 (Org mode 9.4.6)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth]{./kitten.jpg}
\caption{\label{fig:top}Section intro}
\end{figure}
Text below \ref{fig:top}.
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.38\textwidth]{./kitten.jpg}
\caption{\label{fig:left}left figure}
\end{wrapfigure}
I must be on the same line as figure \ref{fig:left}.
\clearwrapfig
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is best to always have a blank line before wrapfigure, ie put it at the start of the paragraph,

Comment: if you use `example-image` as the image then people can run your test file without having to download anything

Comment: This question was actually answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636960/should-i-keep-trying-to-write-a-portfolio-in-org-mode?noredirect=1#comment1587319_636960) as part of a larger question.